# populate data extension with api response based on values in another data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, soap-api, email-studio

we are intending on sending out an email which contains a section with information about events near the customers location/region/city. For this we are using an api from a third party website.

i would like to be able to send the value in the location field ( for example city ) to the third party site and populate a "top event" field wth a link ( the api's response ) which will be different depending on the value in the location field. Doing this prior to email send .

there are other apis at play and i would prefer to populate DE with their response . i intend on using these values in the DEs in other ways.

what steps should i take to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [HTTPGet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/httpget.html) function in ampscript, and fetch the url when the emails are being generated.

If you want to maintain a DE holding the combination of the location and URL, you can user [UpsertDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/upsertde.html) function to store these values in your DE once a response is received from this endpoint.

If the URL is fixed for that particular location, you can do a validation prior to calling the DE with HTTPGet. If the location of your Subscriber exists in the DE, fetch the URL from there (this is more robust and quicker than doing an outbound API call), if not: fetch the data, include in the email and store the URL in your DE.